# What is the Intent to call “Color correction” screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

Is there any way (code) to redirect a user to Color correction.
[image]
As i want to develop an app for color blind ,after asking question,I want to be able to redirect the user directly to the "Color correction" section (inside Accessibility) of the Android settings.and enable that setting (Preferably via a intent)  .Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can only redirect to setting by intent not internal flow of setting.

Comment: There are some app who redirect to specific settings .how they do that?